# SSIS Package fails to execute when run as a SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package that pulls data from one DB to another, with some transformation of the data, that runs correctly when I run the package directly, but throws an error when run with the SQL Agent. The job used to run but is now failing with no identifiable changes in the package.

The error is.

`An item with the same key has already been added.: at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResourse resource) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.StartPackage() at Microsoft.SQLServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.PerformOperation()`

Comment: So no change in the package, how about the job/job step definition?

Comment: As I am looking I can't be sure of that anymore. One of the Control Flows, that wasn't being exercised, wasn't being used, now that I cleared out some data it is causing problems, so my root cause may be there.

Comment: The SSISDB has a built in history of package deployments. Navigate to the Project under the SSIS node and right click and choose Properties (I think). There should be a list of project versions there along with the date. However, the error of `StartPackage` failing smells like something else - permission or a server move/restore *something* is pitching a fit when it's trying to start the package. The package may very well fail once it starts but that error reads like you're trying to use the house key in the automobile ignition

Comment: @billinkc, Your nose seems like it might be onto something. There are no SSIS package history changes between when it work and when it stopped working.
I will need to to dig back into the permissions and see if there is something there to find.

Comment: Just to follow up, I ended up deleting the SQL Agent Job and recreating it. That fixed the problem.